# gmaps not displaying on live website, but works locally

Tags: javascript

Here's the website im trying to get a map on the bottom left:

https://heaps12345.github.io/food/

here is some code snippets:

```
<script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="assets/scripts/gmaps-e77060151c.js"></script>
<div id="map"></div>
<script src="assets/scripts/App-692a674c90.js"></script>

 <script>
 var map = new GMaps({
 div: '#map',
 lat: 37.7578239,
 lng: -122.4481013

 });
 </script>
```

this is my first time deploying a website so after I use "gulp build" task it worked but then when i pushed it to github it wont display.

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools (F12) and look at the errors in the console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify an API key in the script tag

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?key=****************"></script>
```

Have a look [Here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key) for instructions on how to get an API key for your website